# iPhone : How to add different language settings in apps settings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am developing app which contain more then one language.

This app also contain section like `Change Language` containing different language options.

So when one changes the language for example : English to Spanish. It needs to be changed in Spanish language.

My app contains many custom button with different images and that is also need to be changed.

How can I do that ?

Which is the easiest way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way by far is definitely using a macro called NSLocalizedString. What you want to do is called "Localization" here is a link to a good tutorial on how to localize your application in various languages. This tutorial is from english to french. English to spanish is the same principle.

[Localization tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/10/tutorial-part-2-localizing-your-iphone-application/)

Basically what you want to do is declare all your strings as NSLocalizedString and then change depending the language the user has in the device automatically. You will end up making a xib for each language each xib with the button labels etc in the corresponding languages. Then you will generate a text file will all the translations of the NSLocalizedStrings of the program in a UTC16 format. This is only a summary of the tutorial. Follow it it shouldn't be very hard.

Here is an additional link to the internationalization apple documentation:

[Documentation on internationalization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do localization in your application both for strings and images,

Here there is a complete guide for localization =>

http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/

Simply there will be folders for images in any language.

By default localization works with the phone language but you can find in the guide to change it with a settings variables.

For example to use a string tag for any language  `NSLocalizedString(@"tag",nil);`

Where tag will be defined in language files let's say spanish and english

```
"tag" = "englishTag"; // in english file (Named Localizable.Strings )
tag = "tagSpanishTag"; // in spanish file
```

And these files will be the relative language folders with the images.